# Django pagination: "show all" implementation

Tags: ajax, django, pagination, django-pagination

I have a page with a list of objects and two buttons: <kbd>show more</kbd> and <kbd>show all</kbd>. The objects are loaded by AJAX, sending to a `ItemsListView` a page number:

```
class ItemsListView(ListView):
    paginate_by = 2
```

On initializing the page, JS variable `current_page` is set to `1`, and JS sends an AJAX request to `ItemsListView` view, gets 2 objects for the first page and renders them.

When a user clicks on <kbd>show more</kbd> button, `current_page` value increments, and JS requests the objects for the next page.

Now I want to implement <kbd>show all</kbd> button. For example,

If we have the following list of objects: `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]`, on the page load objects `1` and `2` will be rendered. After a user clicks on <kbd>show more</kbd>, it will render objects `3` and `4`. After a user clicks on <kbd>show all</kbd>, it will render objects `5`, `6`, `7`, `8` and `9`.

I changed dynamically `paginate_orphans` in my view:

```
class ItemsListView(ListView):
    paginate_by = 2
    paginate_orphans = 0

    def get_paginate_orphans(self):
        show_all = json.loads(self.request.GET.get('show_all', 'false'))
        page_kwarg = self.page_kwarg
        page = self.kwargs.get(page_kwarg) or self.request.GET.get(page_kwarg) or 1
        if show_all:
            return self.get_queryset().count() - (int(page) - 1) * 2
        return self.paginate_orphans
```

and it worked, but I wonder if there is a more elegant approach to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't elegant at all :D but more obvious ...

```
def get_queryset(self):
    show_all = ...
    page = ...
    qs = super(ItemsListView, self).get_queryset()

    if show_all:
        return qs[int(page)*self.paginate_by:]
    else:
        return qs
```